# python multiprocessing running out of memory work around?

Tags: python, memory, multiprocessing, out-of-memory

I have a script that runs for about 3 hours. If I use multiprocessing, it takes about 20 minutes. The problem is the memory.

Say there is 10 tasks in the script. If I run it on a single core, it will go all the way through. But if I use multiprocessing, I have to stop it half way through to free up the memory and start the second half manually.

I've tried to use garbage `collect`, and using something like `popen` but it doesn't help.

I'm running the script in pycharm. Not sure if that matters on how the memory is handled.

I have 32GB of RAM. When the script starts, I'm already using 6GB. I'm running 64-bit Python 3.6. I have a 12-core processor.

I'm running windows and just using `Pool` from `multiprocessing`.

Running out of memory would make the script bomb. Thus I need to stop it half way and start it again from the 2nd half.

The question is how to run the script all the way through using multiprocessing without using fewer cores?

Comment: can you point me to some documentation? or an example?

Comment: i was just telling to use virtual memory on disk, as much as possible by good ssd.

Comment: Using less processes would be a simple fix.

Comment: Yeah but that would slow me down.

Comment: If you're hitting swap _now_, it will most likely speed you up. You are not showing us how you actually use multiprocessing, do you use `multiprocessing.Pool`?  Which OS?

Comment: Adjust the `processes`-parameter of `Pool` to a value which doesn't result in swapping. Try with `Pool(multiprocessing.cpu_count()//2)` for a start and keep an eye on your system monitor for memory usage.

Comment: I’d have thought running out of memory was slowing you down.